# How to take a screenshot?

Tags: doom-eternal

How do you take an in-game screenshot on PC? I tried <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, but it does not seem to work (only black screen is copied to my clipboard). I'm using Bethesda's launcher on Windows 10.

Comment: Does Bethesda's launcher have a way?

Comment: I assume you're using Windows 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Windows 10,they have a handy feature called the "Game Bar", which has an option to take screenshots.

> The Game bar can’t be found in Start. Instead, you invoke this feature with a special keyboard shortcut: WINKEY + G. Or, if you have an Xbox controller connected to your PC, you can press the Xbox button on the controller instead.

Alternatively, you can use the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>

> The resulting shot is saved in PNG format to the Captures folder in Videos by default. (Visit Settings > Gaming > Game DVR if you’d like to change that.) If you’d like to keep all of your game shots (and game clips) organized, this isn’t a bad way to go: Each screenshot (and clip) is given an easily identifiable file name that includes the name of the game and the date and time at which the shot was made.

[Source](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/106323/windows-10-tip-take-share-game-screenshots)

Comment: Thanks. But wow, that's a complicated key combination for such a frantic game.

Comment: @lukeg You can change that hotkey through the Game Bar's settings.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ben's answer, which is GPU-independent, you can take screenshots with Radeon's Relive using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, or, similarly, with Nvidia's GeForce Experience using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

These default hotkeys can easily be modified to something a lot simpler in their respective panels:

[image: Radeon settings]

[image: GeForce Experience]

Mind, by the way, that the screen capture hotkey of the default Windows 10 Game Bar that Ben mentions can also easily be changed in Windows settings:

[image: Windows Game bar settings]

Answer (score -1):

You can install like Snagit or use the built in Microsoft app in snipping tool